# Active :firstchild styling

Tags: html, css

I'm currently coloring the first element of my menu (via :firstchild pseudo) in different color. However, the first element is sometimes hidden (via display:none) and I want the active first element to be colored.

I was expecting that, hidden elements wouldn't be counted as the firstchild, but it looks like they are still being styled via the :firstchild pseudo.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Well instead of hiding elements you can delete them.

Comment: Would like to see a fiddle of this so I can properly help you.

Comment: Hiding the first child doesn't change the fact that it is the first child... just like when your eldest son leaves the house it doesn't mean you have disowned him or he has disowned you - he's still your eldest son (unless he's running away from home or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="hidden">Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
    <li>Menu Item 4</li>
</ul>

li:first-child {
    color: red;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.hidden + li {
    color: red;
}
```

Where you hide the element by adding a class, and styling the second element with the adjacent child selector (`+`).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xKpAe/)